# Can memers of the public post to my business page via the Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want members of the public to submit posts (images and text) to my business facebook page via an iphone app using the Graph API. Is this possible? If so, could someone explain which calls need to be used in the iphone App (using the Graph API).

I can only see that people with permissions set for the business page can post to it.

I am the developer of the iphone app and it is for public use. I want people to be able to post their game results to the my business facebook page (as well as their own facebook page)

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to request the `publish_actions` permission from your users and with their access token, you can make POST requests to the Graph API at this endpoint:

```
/{page-id}/feed
```

In this POST request you can include a message/link/etc...

For more reference and other accepted parameters, you can take a look at the relevant documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/feed#publish

Comment: Thanks, I'll try implementing this tonight and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks this confirmed it was possible and has put me on the right track. Now I've got to wait for facebook to review the permissions / app